# How can I store ternary operator to the html element in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, ternary-operator, laravel-blade

I have an html element, for example it would be an image, and I want to check my entity for some conditions and depending on this add or do not some class to this element, like this:

```
<div class="btn btn-default">
  {{ HTML::image('//image.png', '', array("class" => "{{{in_array($prod->id, $deleted) ? 'hidden':''}}}")) }}
</div>
```

So, then I have an exception on this line: ***"Array to string conversion"***

Tell me,  please, how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
<div class="btn btn-default">
  {{ HTML::image('//image.png', '', array("class" => in_array($prod->id, $deleted) ? 'hidden':'')) }}
</div>
```

Of course `$prod->id` must be single element (string, integer, float) and `$deleted` must be `array` here. If you still have this message, you need to check types of `$prod->id` and `$deleted`.